# mapping windows to support linux shortcut

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard

I have an italian keyboard, and I'm constantly switching between linux (at home) and windows (at work) shortcut.

As I work on a laptop without a numeric keypad, I found very difficult to insert some characters (as the tilde or the backtick).

(as side note: I have a "fn" button, and I suppose it enables the "numeric keypad simulator" on my "u i o j k l m , ." keys, but they are not visible on my keyboard!!!)

Is there a way to enable linux keys on windows? Ideally I would like to stroke "AltGr-0" to get the tilde and "AltGr-'" to get the backtick. Best of best if I can stroke "AltGr-Shift-'" then "a" or "e" or "i" or "u" to get accented vowels.

Answer (score 0):

Try Autohotkey. http://www.autohotkey.com/

Write yourself a little program to map the keys in any order you like.

Ref::
http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=56481
http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=570#p2854
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey
http://lifehacker.com/5379384/create-a-perfect-customized-boss-key-with-autohotkey